# Return datatables tr index on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to return the index of a given tr when I click on an element inside of a td.

The html

```
    <table class="tablesorter-js">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="txt-align-left>Builder</th>
            <th class=" txt-align-left " jobs">Current jobs</th>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>some text <a class="link" href="#">A link</a>

                    </td>
                    <td>tome more text</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>some text <a class="link" href="#">A link</a>

                    </td>
                    <td>tome more text</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

the javascript

```
$('.link').click(function(e {
e.preventDefault();
console.log(oTable.fnGetPosition(this))
});
```

I know I can invoke the index of the current tr with this

```
var oTable = $('.tablesorter-js').dataTable();
$('.tablesorter-js tbody tr').click( function () {
    var pos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this)    
    // I want the position of the tr element when I click on .link              
    return pos;
});
```

How do I get that index of the current tr element when I click on .link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log( $(this).closest('tr').index() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get index of current `<tr>` element whose link is clicked with below jQuery code:

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest('tr').index());
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rwzy3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use index() jQuery function

```
var oTable = $('.tablesorter-js').dataTable();
$('.tablesorter-js tbody tr').click( function () {
    //var pos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this)       
    var idx = $(this).index(".tablesorter-js tbody tr");     
    return idx;
});

$('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log( $(this).closest('tr').index(".tablesorter-js tbody tr") );
});
```

For more details [.index() JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/index/)